# Side-scrolling images with captions

Tags: css, html, overflow

I'm designing a website that uses side-scrolling strips of cells containing images with description beside the image.

```
+----------------------------------+  +----------------------------------+
|+--------+   Title                |  |+--------+   Title                |
|| Image  |   Description...       |  || Image  |   Description...       |
||        |                        |  ||        |                        |
|+--------+                        |  |+--------+                        |
+----------------------------------+  +----------------------------------+
```

All attempts by me to produce line breaks of any sort necessary for separating title from description results in vertical scrolling instead of side scrolling. Here's some of my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 250px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .scrolling {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .cell {
        display: inline;
        height: 250px;
        width: 500px;
    }
</style>
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- The following approach sort of works but is all in a line -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="scrolling">
                <div class="cell">
                    <img src="/static/pic1.jpg" height="200" />
                    title1 description1
                </div>
                <div class="cell">
                    <img src="/static/pic2.jpg" height="200" />
                    title2 description2
                </div>
                <!-- etcetera -->
            </div>
        </div>
    <body/>
</html>
```

I tried to use float in the css but any use of it causes the undesired wrapping of .cell divs in the .scrolling div. Whats the best approach to creating this effect?

Comment: did you also try `display: inline-block` instead of `display: inline`?

Comment: Great, that did the trick! Do you want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `display: inline-block` instead of `display: inline`

remember to also set a negative letter-spacing and word-spacing

```
.scrolling {
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-spacing: -3px;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
}
.cell {
    display: inline-block;
    word-spacing: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    white-space : normal;

    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
}
```